# Javascript Object.defineProperty set method trigger on property change

Tags: javascript, object, coffeescript, setter, ecmascript-5

Take the following (coffeescript) example of a Person class with a details property, which in turn has its own properties:

```
class Person
  constructor: ->
    details =
      name: ''
      age: 0

    Object.defineProperty this, 'details',
      enumerable: yes
      get: => details
      set: (value) =>
        console.log 'set details:', value
        details = value

p = new Person

# does NOT trigger details set()
p.details.name = 'Simon'

# DOES trigger details set(), but takes a bit of effort...
details = p.details
details.name = 'Someone else'
p.details = details
```

Obviously, if I were to just define name and age as properties of the Person class I could avoid this problem, but this is just an example.

Is there any simple way to get my details set() method to fire when its properties are changed?

Answer (score 2):

Not really. At least not simply.

`p` is totally different object than `p.details`.  Modifying `p.details` doesn't change anythings about `p` at all.  So it wont get a message.

What you would have to do is install some code that makes the details object send a message to its parent when it's own properties change. Which also means that it needs to know what it's parent is.

```
class Person
  constructor: ->
    details =
      name: ''
      age: 0

    Object.defineProperty this, 'details',
      enumerable: yes
      get: -> details
      set: (value) ->
        console.log 'set details:', value
        details = value

        # set parent object to tell when something changes
        value._parent = this

        # create a name setter, which tells it's parent when it changes.
        Object.defineProperty details, 'name',
          enumerable: yes
          get: -> @_name
          set: (value) ->
            @_parent.didUpdateDetails()

     # trigger setter to install hook
     @details = details

   didUpdateDetails: ->
     console.log 'Updated details!'

p = new Person
p.details.name = 'Alex'
# logs: "Updated details!"
```

And yeah, that really works: http://jsfiddle.net/PkyaU/1/

But honestly, that's a little crazy.  Are you sure this is what you need to do? Maybe you should rethink your approach.